Is it possible to have multiple sets of TestRunParameters in a RunSettings file?
I'm wanting to test multiple different user permissions within an Integration library test project where the data is structured as
<TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="ClientNumber" value="ABC" />
    <Parameter name="Username" value="A@BC" />
    <Parameter name="Company" value="Meta" />
</TestRunParameters>

But for different endpoints users have different permissions, such as Accounts, Cards, etc
Is it possible to specify differently named groups of TestRunParameters for example:
<TestRunParameters name="CardUser">
and then call from my code:
string username = TestContext["CardUser"].Parameters["username"]
or does TestContext not allow this?
Is it correct to keep going down the runsettings route or should I refactor my test project to make use of a general settings xml file?
